# How to bind array to dropdownlist with condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays

This might be a duplicate question, but I was not able to find any helpful answer for this query.

I have an array of a class **LevelDetails** which I am getting from a web service. Each array item has a property named "Level". Every employee has a level assigned to him.  If the level value is 3, then I need to bind the dropdownlist with the array items having level less than 3.

I know how to bind the dropdownlist with the array. But I am not able to figure out how to specify the condition.

Comment: can you post some of your code . what have you tried so far!

Comment: check my answer and tell me if you need something else ?

Answer (score 0):

```
        List<BO.TestClass> list = new List<BO.TestClass>();

        BO.TestClass c1 = new BO.TestClass();
        c1.Level = 4;
        list.Add(c1);

        BO.TestClass c2 = new BO.TestClass();
        c2.Level = 3;
        list.Add(c2);

        BO.TestClass c3 = new BO.TestClass();
        c3.Level = 9;
        list.Add(c3);

        BO.TestClass c4 = new BO.TestClass();
        c4.Level = 2;
        list.Add(c4);

        BO.TestClass c5 = new BO.TestClass();
        c5.Level = 1;
        list.Add(c5);

        BO.TestClass c6 = new BO.TestClass();
        c6.Level = 8;
        list.Add(c6);

        List<BO.TestClass> test = list.Where(x => x.Level > 3).ToList();
```

If I understand you properly you need something like this. After that bind test to your DropDownList.